# Clearing the update log on postgresql DB

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

What I am trying to do is to call a function whenever there is an update to the DB. I use the ***'Committed transaction information'*** aspect to get the status on the DB update.

```
pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xid)
SELECT pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin) ts FROM  "TABLE_NAME" WHERE pg_xact_commit_timestamp(xmin) IS NOT NULL;
```

The problem: After the first-iteration of update to the DB. The commit_timestamp(xmin) would never be empty. Is there a way that once the functions is executed we can set the commit_timestamp list to be empty?

My requirement: To execute a function only when there is an new (without any information on the previous update) update

I understand that, this is over use of an inbuilt-function.

E.g.

```
Connection DBconn = DBConnection.connect(url,user,password);
Boolean DBStatus = checkDBStatus(DBconn, configuration);
if(DBStatus) {
    System.out.println("DB updated recently");
    feedbackStatusJSON = runBusinessLogic();
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("DB not updated");
    }
```

Comment: please rephrase. what is your initial goal?

Comment: To execute a function only when there is an new (without any information on the previous update) update

Comment: please some code scenario

Comment: What do you mean with "when there is a new update"? Update on what? A specific table? Any table in the database? A specific row in a table? A specific column in a table?

Comment: update on a specific table

Comment: You might use [triggers](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/triggers.html).